# How I can store uploaded images in different folders thereby automatically generating the folders?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

After I created the html file for uploading an image, I need to store each image uploaded automatically in different folders having different names.

Only the image file name would be shown in database.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getFileInfo($name, $uniqueId, $mediaDir)
{
    $filename = preg_replace('#[^a-z]+#i', '_', $name);
    $filename .= '_'.$uniqueId.'_'.$mediaDir.'.pdf';            
    $mediapath = $mediaDir.DS.$filename[0].DS.$filename[1]; // dispersion
    $destinationFolder = {{write basedirectory url}}.DS.$mediapath;
    if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {
        echo 'Unable to create directory'.$destinationFolder; //Some error message
    }
    return array(
        'filename'    => $filename,
        'mediapath'   => $mediapath.DS.$filename,
        'fullpath'    => $destinationFolder.DS.$filename
    );
}
```

> This function will create different folders for each upload.Before
>   save, Please call this function and save any of the returned
>   values(filename, mediapath, fullpath) in database.
>
> $uniqueId - Specific Entity ID   $mediaDir - Where to save (Folder
>   path)   $name     - Eg. (Name of uploader)
>
> Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific you can use `@mkdir()` function for creating directory automatically
four parameters you need to provide in this function first two are essential while other 2 are optional

```
@mkdir($sdirectory_path.'/'.$folder_name, 0777,true)
```

1. Path to directory with file name where you are going to store you images
2. Permission to the folder use 0777 for all permissions granted
3. Use true for granting recursive permission